# Not equivalent REST code between php and ruby

Tags: ruby, rest, rest-client

I need to post to a REST resource by using ruby `rest-client` gem.

The example of HTTP request is:

```
POST /somefolder HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YWFhOmFw
Host: example.com
folder: creat
```

and it provides a demo code written in php, and works well:

```
<?php
$process = curl_init('example.com/somefolder'); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('folder: true'));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
print(curl_exec($process)."<br/>"); 
print(curl_getinfo($process, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT).'<br/>');
curl_close($process);
?>
```

My ruby code is:

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new('http://example.com/', :user => 'username', :password => 'password')
resource.post 'somefolder', :folder => 'true'
```

But it returns 403 forbidden. I'd like to know where my ruby is wrong. Thanks.

BTW, how can I capture the HTTP traffic sent by ruby code? I am using MAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not the most familiar with Ruby but I think there are two issues with your code. `somefolder` is being sent as the content instead of the path and the folder `folder` is getting modified. What I think the ruby request will look like is this.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YWFhOmFw
Host: example.com
X-Folder: true

somefolder
```

My reading of the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.7/RestClient/Resource) suggest that switching to the following will fix the path but I'm not sure if you can fix the header name client side.

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new('http://example.com/', :user => 'username', :password => 'password')
resource['somefolder'].post, :folder => 'true'
```

You may have to include an empty string or a null value for the content.

Use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to view HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks abraham, it works. Actually, the more correct code is `resource['somefolder'].post '', :folder => 'true' `